# Use of System.Reflection.Missing.Value in Exporting DataGridView to MS Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, datagridview

What is the reason why it is needed to use System.Reflection.Missing.Value when exporting DataGridView data into MS Excel like shown in the code below?

```
    Dim missValue As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(missValue)
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for `C#` code since it does not allow for `Optional` parameters. It is not needed in VB, but won't hurt either. You can always specify the parameter you are supplying: `paramName:=value`